# swift 4 write to text file on server (http or smb)

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to write to a text file on a windows server through http or smb (e.g smb://192.168.0.4/test/text.txt)
Reading from is not a problem but I cannot write to it (getting various errors such as http/smb not supported). I also tried via urlsession, nshandler, but all unsuccessful.
Any help would be really appreciated.